# HTML add downslide animation to texts once the site loads

Tags: javascript, html, css

I looked at some articles on the internet but I couldn't find what I wanted. After the site loads for the first time, when I scroll and scroll to a paragraph, I want the text to scroll from the bottom and come after 1 second.Like on this site:https://www.armoli.com/.
For example I want to apply it here

```
<h6 style="margin-right: 70px;" class="section-title text-center">Our Solutions</h6>
           
            <h6 style="margin-right: 120px;" class="section-subtitle text-center mb-5 pb-3">We offer efficient, high performance and guaranteed solutions with our experienced team having strong references</h6>

         <div class="solutionout1">
            <img class="solu" style="height:80px ;" src="assets/imgs/webdevelop.png" alt="web development logo" >
<div ><p class="solutionhead">Web Development</p><p class="solutiontext">

    We offer fast, profitable, safe and effective solutions in the light of the latest innovations to those who entrust us with their companies' showcases in the internet world.</p></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML, CSS, and JavaScript scroll reveal animations**

```js
    window.addEventListener('scroll', reveal);

    function reveal(){
      var reveals = document.querySelectorAll('.reveal');

      for(var i = 0; i < reveals.length; i++){

        var windowheight = window.innerHeight;
        var revealtop = reveals[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var revealpoint = 150;

        if(revealtop < windowheight - revealpoint){
          reveals[i].classList.add('active');
        }
        else{
          reveals[i].classList.remove('active');
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  background: #1D212B;
}

section{
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

section:nth-child(1){
  color: #fff;
}

section:nth-child(2){
  color: #1D212B;
  background: #fff;
}

section:nth-child(3){
  color: #fff;
}

section:nth-child(4){
  color: #1D212B;
  background: #fff;
}

section .container{
  margin: 100px;
}

section h1{
  font-size: 60px;
}

section h2{
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

section .cards{
  display: flex;
}

section .cards .text-card{
  background: #2696E9;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

section .cards .text-card h3{
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 900px){
  section h1{
    font-size: 40px;
  }

  section .cards{
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.reveal{
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(150px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.reveal.active{
  transform: translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Scroll Reveal</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <section>
      <h1>Reveal Elements On Scroll</h1>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class="container reveal">
        <h2>Your Title</h2>
        <div class="cards">
          <div class="text-card">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="text-card">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="text-card">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class="container reveal">
        <h2>Your Title</h2>
        <div class="cards">
          <div class="text-card">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="text-card">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="text-card">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class="container reveal">
        <h2>Your Title</h2>
        <div class="cards">
          <div class="text-card">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="text-card">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="text-card">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked, but the animation works every time I scroll. Can I make it work only once and then resume the normal order?

Comment: Hopefully, I'll be able to update it soon after trying it

Answer (score 0):

```js
const intersectionCallback = (entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      let elem = entry.target;
      if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.75) {
        elem.classList.add("animate");
      }
    }
  });
};

const Animateditems = document.querySelectorAll("div.text");
let options = {
  threshold: 1.0,
};
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(intersectionCallback, options);

Animateditems.forEach((item) => {
  observer.observe(item);
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
html {
  font-size: 66.6%;
}
.scrolldown {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 2rem;
}
.flex-container > div {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  border: 0.1rem solid black;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.flex-container > div.animate p {
  animation: fadeIn 2s;
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-container > div.animate h2 {
  animation: fadeIn 2s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.flex-container > div h2 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(0rem);
}
.flex-container > div p {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  opacity: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .flex-container > div {
    flex: 1 1 40%;
    border: 0.1rem solid black;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    transform: translateY(2rem);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0rem);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>animation</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="scrolldown"><h1>scroll down</h1></div>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="text">
        <h2>This is a title</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel
          inventore, aut id laboriosam reprehenderit consectetur? Praesentium,
          aperiam corporis. Iste asperiores molestiae, itaque a minus dicta! Id
          omnis suscipit iure illum.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <h2>This is a title</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel
          inventore, aut id laboriosam reprehenderit consectetur? Praesentium,
          aperiam corporis. Iste asperiores molestiae, itaque a minus dicta! Id
          omnis suscipit iure illum.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <h2>This is a title</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel
          inventore, aut id laboriosam reprehenderit consectetur? Praesentium,
          aperiam corporis. Iste asperiores molestiae, itaque a minus dicta! Id
          omnis suscipit iure illum.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <h2>This is a title</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel
          inventore, aut id laboriosam reprehenderit consectetur? Praesentium,
          aperiam corporis. Iste asperiores molestiae, itaque a minus dicta! Id
          omnis suscipit iure illum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a complete vanilla solution. (open it in full screen mode)